# Force Tabbed Dock in QMainWindow Qt5.7

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get my QMainWindow to allow only tabbed QDockWidgets. If I understood the Qt Documentation right it should work with the setDockOptions-method.

The following code didn't work for me:

```
 QMainWindow window;
 window.setDockOptions(QMainWindow::ForceTabbedDocks);
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug in the current Qt version? I'm coding on a MacPro an I'm using Qt 5.7.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

`ForceTabbedDocks` only applies to user interactions with the docks.

To programatically add new docks in tabs, you need to use `QMainWindow::tabifyDockWidgets`. For example,

```
void MainWindow::addTabbedDock(Qt::DockWidgetArea area, QDockWidget *widget)
{
    QList<QDockWidget*> allDockWidgets = findChildren<QDockWidget*>();
    QVector<QDockWidget*> areaDockWidgets;
    for(QDockWidget *w : allDockWidgets) {
        if(dockWidgetArea(w) == area) {
            areaDockWidgets.append(w);
        }
    }

    if(areaDockWidgets.empty()) {
        // no other widgets
        addDockWidget(area, widget);
    } else {
        tabifyDockWidget(areaDockWidgets.last(), widget);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same answer as @Xian Nox, but adapted for python:

```
def addTabbedDock(self, area: QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea, dockwidget: QtWidgets.QDockWidget):
  curAreaWidgets = [d for d in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDockWidget)
                    if self.dockWidgetArea(d) == area]
  try:
    self.tabifyDockWidget(curAreaWidgets[-1], dockwidget)
  except IndexError:
    # First dock in area
    self.addDockWidget(area, dockwidget)
```

Comment: I prefer the following adaptation, but nice answer.
if curAreaWidgets:
    self.tabifyDockWidget(curAreaWidgets[-1], dockwidget)
else:
    self.addDockWidget(area, dockwidget)